# Inverse Function Theorem (results using it)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Hi i'm thinking in some ideas for my bachelor thesis. I'm working in a more "general" framework than manifolds, and i found that the Inverse Function Theorem is valid in such structures. So i was thinking if you know some interesting results that are proved or disproved using the Inverse Function Theorem (with their references if possible) so i could try to prove(or disprove) one of them in such framework for my thesis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What structures do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm starting to work in supermanifolds.

Comment: So, how would you state the IFT for supermanifolds? The natural beginning in manifolds is giving standard local forms of maps of constant rank.

Comment: A supermanifold is a manifold with a extra structure, a sheaf of algebras (and it's seems the most basic is using Grassman algebras for what i've been reading), and for the statement of IFT is used the Dewitt's topology. But the statement of IFT for supermanifolds is almost the same than the one for manifolds.

Comment: I assume it's a statement about the underlying map on manifolds, with some induced map on the sheaf. So, yeah, what about immersions, submersions, etc.?

Comment: Suppose U is an open subset of $R^{m,n}_S$ (in the DeWitt topology) and that F:U$\rightarrow$ $R^{m,n}_S$ is $G^{\infty}$. Then, if the (m,n)x(m,n) supermatrix of derivatives ($\partial^{s}_k{F^j}$) is invertible at a point (x,$\xi$) in U, there exist a neighbourhood V of (x,$\xi$) such that F$\vert_V$:V$\rightarrow$F(V) has a $G^{\infty}$ inverse G; also the derivatives of G satisfy

Comment: I still don't finish to understand completely the proof but is almost the same that with manifolds, just argues something extra about the number of the generators of the Grassman algebra.